# InfoPath form published into a Content Type Hub doesn't load in web browser in consuming libraries

Tags: 2010, infopath, content-type, forms-services, content-type-hub

We are deploying several content types to an organisation via the Content Type Hub functionality of the Managed Metadata Service in SharePoint 2010.

Our main focus at the moment is Project Server and the Project sites that are spawned for each project.

Within these, we would like to have some InfoPath forms to capture certain job information, such as what they call 'job sheets' which are filled out by the on-site engineer team and returned to the office. They only need to be stored against the project site, so we are attempting to deploy the InfoPath form to the Project Sites via the content type hub. This way, if the form needs to be updated, all existing and new Project Sites alike will receive the new version of the form.

However, we've hit several stumbling blocks:

- The first being that we couldn't store the InfoPath files in a library in the CTH, because when the document library in the project site (which is in a different web application) went to use it, InfoPath services failed because the content type only contained a relative link to the template; which doesn't exist on the PWA web application. There is no way to specify an absolute path instead, so we had to use the "browse" option to link the template to the CT instead.
- The second problem that has shown itself is that once this is done, the InfoPath form (which otherwise works fine in the browser within the CTH) only wants to load in the full-fledged InfoPath local client - this is not ideal as some locations that will use this form will not have InfoPath installed.

Therefore my question is this; is there some sort of secret art to publishing InfoPath forms via a Content Type hub, or is it just not possible due to the way the XSN template file 'binds' to the site you publish it to?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried publishing the InfoPath forms as admin approved forms?

We have forms working in Content Type Hubs but it seems that they need to be admin approved to open in the browser.

Comment: Hrmm... I thought I did try this, but still when the form was clicked on, the URL would show only a relative path to the form. Is your Content Type Hub in the same web application as where you used the Content Type? Did you setup a Submit handler for the form? Or did you just rely on the Save button?